# CSS float not being applied in Chrome... bug or user error?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-float

I'm trying to track down an intermittent Chrome rendering bug in my web application.

When toggling the float property between "left" and "none" Chrome does not refloat the elements. Firefox and IE behave as expected.

Click on the "account-info" div to toggle the float values.

```js
var $items = $(".menu > span");
$("#account-info").on("click", function () {
    if ($items.css("float") === "left") {
        $items.css("float", "none"); 
    } else {
        $items.css("float", "left"); 
    }
});
```

```css
#account-info {
    float: right;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.menu .icon {
    display: block;
}
.menu span {
    /*display: block;*/
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="account-info">
    <div class="menu">
        <span class="icon">[left-icon]</span>
        <span>User Name</span>
        <span class="icon">[right-icon]</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If `display:block;` is uncommented then Chrome does refloat the elements, but I was always under the impression that it was unnecessary to declare `display:block` when specifying `float:left` or `float:right` Reference: [Implied Block | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/implied-block/)

So is this a bug in Chrome or I am missing something here?

Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71m / Windows 8.1 64-bit

Comment: It seems to float correctly with or without the `display:block` for me in Chrome.

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Comment: However I do notice the odd stacking of the `<span>`s when all the floats are removed.

Comment: @j08691 Code moved from JSFiddle to post

Comment: @philtune Removed reference to JQueryUI for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Give `#account-info` a width.

Since it itself is floating, it takes on the width of its contents in Chrome. Thus, when you click the first time it collapses to the width of "User Name" and never reverts.

Comment: The left-floated items shouldn't wrap unless they are being constrained by any parent elements or the viewport. Setting a width on `#account-info` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: "Shouldn't" - maybe so. But that's how Chrome is behaving. Adding a width fixes the prob.